# Plone+Python - How to automatically set content item to be default view of the folder?

Tags: python, plone

I use xmlrpclib, wsapi4plone to upload stuff to plone. 
Say I'm going to create a folder:

```
client = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('http://user:password@blah.com/plone')         
f = {'blah.com/plone/folder': 
     [
        {'title': folder},
        'Folder', None,
     ]
    }
print 'Creating...', client.post_object(f)
```

then upload a page in that folder:

```
page = {'blah.com/plone/filename':
         [
            {'title':filename, 'text':file.read()},
             'Document',None,
         ]
       }
client.post_object(page)
```

How do I set the folder to use this page for its default view through python?
Also, I am not the admin, just a normal user just so you know..
Could you please help? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you are looking for is `setDefaultPage` on the folder. If you have the right to set the default page through the web with your user, you have the same right via XML-RPC, access control is method agnostic. `setDefaultPage` takes the id of the page object as an argument.

`setDefaultPage` is part of the [`ISelectableBrowserDefault` interface](https://dev.plone.org/browser/collective/CMFDynamicViewFTI/trunk/Products/CMFDynamicViewFTI/interfaces.py#L84), take a look at that for more details.

Comment: so in order to use that method, i have to install CMFDynamicViewI package? is it kind of separate from xmlrpc? I only know to connect to plone by xmlrpc

Comment: No, folders implement that interface already, it is part of stock Plone. The methods on that interface are web published, so accessible from XML-RPC too.

Comment: Thank you. It looks like this is the right way to do it :D although i bump into this problem xmlrpclib.ProtocolError: <ProtocolError for blah.com/plone/: 401 Unauthorized> I will find a work around this. Thank you!!